# Каким образом перезагрузить named из php-скрипта?

Tags: php, bash, администрирование

Есть VPS с centos 7 с root доступом. Необходимо время от времени из php скрипта выполнять там команду:

```
systemctl reload named.service
```

Результат выполнения команды exec('whoami'):

```
apache
```

Исходя из этого команда

```
exec('systemctl reload named.service', $arr);
```

не сработает? Может есть решение?

Может можно дать юзеру apache рут права? Как это сделать? И в плане безопасности, это безопасно?

На крайний случай может накидаете bash скрипт и подскажете как его запустить из php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Создаем bash скрипт под рутом, скажем он будет /usr/local/bin/namereload.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
systemctl reload named.service
```

Внимание: лучше указать в скрипте полный путь к systemctl, т.к. скорее всего он лежит где нибудь в /sbin или /usr/sbin, а этих путей может не быть в PATH во время выполнения php скрипта. Сам скрипт обязательно должен быть создан рутом и в каталоге доступном на запись только руту (и на чтение всем), что бы его содержимое не мог поменять непривилегированный пользователь.

Делаем скрипт выполнимым `chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/namereload.sh`

В /etc/sudoers добавляем строку:

```
apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/namereload.sh
```

В php скрипте пишем:

```
exec('sudo /usr/local/bin/namereload.sh');
```

В таком варианте все абсолютно безопасно. Единственная команда, которую может выполнить под рутом пользователь apache это перезапуск named.

Comment: Спасибо, наверное так и сделаю. Ещё хотел спросить, а что если в файле /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf изменить 
user = apache
group = apache

Comment: @sashaeee Изменить на что, он же у вас и так уже apache

Comment: Спасибо, наверное так и сделаю. Ещё хотел спросить, а что если в файле /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf изменить 
user = apache
group = apache на user = root group = root, так по идее php из под рута будет работать и в функции exec() можно будет выполнять любые команды? В плане безопасности это безопасно будет? (учитывая что на VPS не будет накиких других пользователей, кроме меня)

Comment: @sashaeee давать рута php скриптам не стоит. В каком нибудь из скриптов вполне может быть какая либо ошибка, например позволяющая получить произвольный файл. Если скрипт будет под рутом то он сможет получить файл паролей. Так же, если папки где лежат скрипты не доступны на запись пользователю апач, то внедрить какой либо код через ошибки в скриптах крайне проблематично. А под рутом можно сходу через веб внедрятся в любую часть системы

Comment: К сожалению так и не получилось мне запустить мой скрипт( Я создал файл /home/bash/namedreload.sh, сделал скрипт выполнимым, в конец файла etc/sudoers добавил `apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/bash/namedreload.sh` но в скрипте exec('sudo /home/bash/namedreload.sh'); не работает( При это если через putty войти на сервер под рутом и выполнить в командной строке sudo /home/bash/namedreload.sh все работает (я для проверки писал туда #!/bin/sh cd /home
mkdir 123). Может быть подскажете в чем может быть дело? VPS я перезагружал.

Comment: И ещё Вы не могли бы пояснить фразу "Внимание: лучше указать в скрипте полный путь к systemctl" где взять полный путь и как его указать?

Comment: @sashaeee просто загляните в каталоги /sbin, /usr/sbin думаю в одной из них он есть. ну или менее вероятно в /bin, /usr/bin. И тогда прямо с путем и пишите команду, типа  /usr/sbin/systemctl

Comment: все же вариант, который вы дали выше - нерабочий. Вчера целый день до полуночи гуглил, перепробовал десятки вариантов. В итоге сегодня у меня заработал такой вариант: В /etc/sudoers добавляем %apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/bash/namedreload.sh В этом же файле комментируем строку # Defaults    requiretty И главное, php функцию exec запускаем в таком виде: exec('sudo -u root -S /home/bash/namedreload.sh'); Но все равно спасибо, что пытались помочь)