# Как запустить процесс на debian 7 через PHP

Tags: php, debian, vps, процесс

Как запустить процесс на debian 7 через PHP?

```
<?php
    $output = shell_exec('/root/testsrv ./samp03svr &');
?>
```

- не работает. Все происходит на одном виртуальном сервере, файл **.php** находится в **/var/www**

Comment: А вы уверены, что пользователю под которым работает php доступен каталог /root. Обычно он доступен только руту и собственно так и должно быть

Comment: @Mike, нет. Об этом я даже не подумал. Возможно ли дать доступ пользователю под которым работает php? Как это сделать? Безопасно ли это или лучше реализовывать это по другому?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/507004/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-named-%D0%B8%D0%B7-php-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0/507015#507015

Comment: лучше реализовать это по-другому — поместить файлы туда, где они будут доступны для чтения пользователю, от имени которого выполняется ваш скрипт (скорее всего, это *www-data*). например, в тот же `/var/www/какой/нибудь/каталог`

Comment: @Mike, этот вариант у меня почему то не работает. Пробовал все варианты описанные в теме.

Comment: @alexander barakin, вы о **.php** файле? Он там. Не совсем вас понял.

Comment: @ES. Посмотрите там комментарии, на разных системах оно как то по разному работает. проверяйте сначала команды с консоли. И да, вопрос в том, а нужно ли вам что бы тот процесс работал под рутом.  И еще, если он не умеет отвязываться от управляющего терминала то возможно стоит его запускать как `nohup процесс &`

Comment: @ES., я о `/root/testsrv` и `/root/samp03svr`

Comment: @Mike, Пробовал запустить через консоль, пишет: **/usr/local/bin/onsrv.sh: 2: /usr/local/bin/onsrv.sh: /root/testsrv: Permission denied**. В самом файле, первая строка: **#!/bin/sh**, вторая: **/root/testsrv ./samp03svr &**

Comment: @alexander barakin, так не получиться, так как с этим файлом связано еще много всяких разных файлов, присутствует конфиденциальная информация.

Comment: А где собственно sudo при вызове ? sudo в любом случае что то должно сделать, выдать ошибку что вообще нельзя, спросить пароль или отработать без пароля штатно. И ./samp03svr берется из текущего каталога в момент запуска а не /root/samp03svr

Comment: @Mike, путь в файле изменил на **/root/testsrv samp03svr &**. При запуске выдает ошибку: sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 28
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin. 28 строка: **apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/onsrv.sh**, а ниже ничего больше нет.

Comment: @ES. Вы самый последний комментарий под моим ответом прочитали ? Там ТС пишет что ему пришлось закоментарить Defaults requiretty и перед apache процент написать. Про это ничего сказать не могу, потому как в моем sudo ничего подобного нет

Comment: @Mike, да, конечно. Я все варианты из той темы пробовал. Попробовал еще раз - тоже самое. Так выглядит файл **/etc/sudoers**: http://i.imgur.com/XgRHoBd.png

Comment: @ES. У меня файл даже проще, нет всяких Define. Не знаю зачем они в вашем дистрибутиве. А ошибка на которую он ругается именно на добавленной строке ? А если эту строку закоментарить, sudo что нибудь вообще работает

Comment: @Mike, всегда показывает последнюю, вне зависимости от текста строки. При запуске процесса на прямую - та же ошибка. Видимо что то с sudo.

Comment: @ES. А чем вы файл правили. Может там теперь какой нибудь виндовый перевод каретки затесался. Мне кажется sudo может быть чувствительным. Или права доступа на файл изменились. Он должен принадлежать root с правами 0440 (т.е. r--r-----)

Comment: @Mike, файл создал при помощи программы WinSCP, права 755 (rwxr-xr-x)

Comment: ну тогда поменяйте обратно `chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers`

Comment: @Mike, тоже самое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение:
Был создан кастомный .**sh** скрипт включения/выключения/перезагрузки сервера, работающий при помощи **screen**

```
cd $path
screen -dmS $screenName ./samp03svr &
echo "Ok"
```

, и **.php** скрипт:

```
shell_exec('bash /var/www/CP/server.sh start');
```

Автор: **Disinterpreter**