# Добавил пользователя в группу root, однако не все выполняется без sudo

Tags: linux, access, root

проверяю

```
members root
```

он (мой пользователь) там. Однако выполняю некоторую программу, которая нормально функционирует через **sudo** - без sudo не работает, с sudo - да (как и раньше, до добавления его в группу root).

Выполняю (**без** явного sudo):

```
mount -o remount,rw xxx yyy
```

(для примера). Пишет:

```
mount: only root can use "--options" option
```

Под sudo опять таки нормально проходит (sudo mount -o ...).

Хотя некоторые права и добавились, которых раньше не было, например листать некоторые папки можно теперь без явного sudo, но почему я не могу выполнить все что угодно **без sudo** под пользователем, находящимся в группе **root**?

**Дополнительный вопрос** - как мне выполнять все что угодно без sudo каким-то заданным пользователем (не root'ом), что для этого надо с ним сделать (как видно добавление в группу root недостаточно)

**Моя цель - выполнить некую программу через скрипт с правами рута, а скрипт запускается под определенным пользователем (не рутом).**

Comment: chown 644 FILENAME? разве это не будет работать?

Comment: @Insider вы имели в виду `chmod`?

Comment: @Insider На mount точно ничего не повлияет. Это суидная программа и она сама проверяет все права доступа перед выполнением операций

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Значит на те папки которые вы теперь видите для группы root есть соответствующие права, вот вы их и видите. А на какой нибудь /etc/shadow права только для пользователя root, но не для группы и вы его не увидите. А каждая программа (вроде mount) сама решает доверять ей группе root или требовать именно пользователя.

Нормального способа выполнять все, что угодно пользователю отличному от root не существует. Единственный способ - создать отдельный исполняемый shell (сделать копию с какого нибудь zsh) поставить этому шеллу права на запуск только для группы root, назначить владельца root и выставить SUID-бит прав доступа. После этого если вы запустите этот shell вы получите все права root. Но это очень небезопасно, ибо любой кто сможет его запустить станет рутом. Так что гораздо проще явно стать рутом, что бы выполнить нужные действия. Используя тот же `sudo` или выполнив `su -`

Comment: Мне нужно выполнить некую программу через скрипт с правами рута, а скрипт запускается под определенным пользователем (не рутом).

Comment: @asianirish Так запускайте программу из скрипта через sudo или сам скрипт через sudo. А в sudoers для пользователя который запускает этот скрипт пропишите права на запуск этой программы/скрипта без запроса пароля

Comment: О! То что нужно, спасибо за направление копания!

Comment: @asianirish Вот, посмотрите этот ответ  http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/507004/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-named-%D0%B8%D0%B7-php-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0/507015#507015

Comment: рецепт работает, если написать **sudo команда** из терминала (не просит пароль). Но если написать в скрипте (.sh) **sudo эта_же_команда**, то не проходит

Comment: @asianirish Ну это странно. как будто у вас скрипт под другим пользователем запускается. Вы его сами запускаете, прямо из консоли

Answer (score 3):

**root** - это специальный пользователь в unix и многие операции (подключение/отключение устройств, смена пароля другому пользователю, создание/удаление пользователя и т.п.) может делать только рут.
**sudo** - это штатный способ получения прав рута, не зная его пароля.

**Группа root** - это просто группа, она даёт только права на файловую систему. Поэтому, ответ на ваш вопрос *почему я не могу выполнить все что угодно без sudo под пользователем, находящимся в группе root?* - потому что так задумано. 
Есть варианты добавления еще одного рута (с другим именем) в систему, но судя по вашему уровню знания linux - вам этого делать не стоит.

На вопрос же *как мне выполнять все что угодно без sudo каким-то заданным пользователем (не root'ом)* - ответ **никак**. Всё, что угодно, можно выполнить только пользователем root (пользователем с ID 0).

Comment: Мне нужно выполнить некую программу через скрипт с правами рута, а скрипт запускается под определенным пользователем (не рутом).

Comment: Почитайте про SUID-бит и решите, подойдёт это вам или нет. Но это ОГРОМНАЯ дыра в безопасности сервера.