# Программная перезагрузка Linux c помощью Python

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

В одном из моих мелких скриптов потребовалось реализовать программную перезагрузку компьютера под управлением Ubuntu. Не подскажите, как это проще всего сделать на Python? Скрипт работает не под рутом!

Comment: вызвать /sbin/reboot как обычную внешнюю программу через какой нибудь os.exec

Comment: для этого sudo потребуется, нужно пароль будет ввести...

Comment: а почему в вопросе не указано, что скрипт работает не под рутом, это основное условие. хотя в принципе это не имеет значения. sudo отлично умеет не спрашивать пароль на определенные действия, запрос в гугле "sudo без пароля" выдает массу вариантов. или тут посмотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/507015/194569

Comment: Если убунта, то можно `systemctl reboot` через `subprocess.Popen`.

Comment: А можно подробнее показать, как через `subprocess.Popen`?

Comment: Спасибо! Сделал через `subprocess.Popen`

Comment: @Mike судо без пароля это идея не очень. сложно переносить и перенастраивать. лучше вызвать "правильную" утилиту или обратиться по dbus к powermanager

Comment: @eri вы хотите сказать, что каким то обращением по dbus можно обойти основную защиту ОС и любой желающий сможет перезагрузить комп. что то слабо верится, слишком большая дыра в безопасности. все равно должен существовать некий суиндный процесс, который сам проверит привилегии и выполнит требуемое действие.

Comment: любой может перезагрузить комп через кнопку в меню - кнопка в меню стукает дбас. дыра-не дыра, а привелегия есть у юзеров комп перезагружать

Comment: повер менеджер проверяет привелегии

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделал, как мне рекомендовали:

`softreset = subprocess.Popen(['systemctl', 'reboot'])`

Comment: сработает только если нет других сессий открытых

Answer (score 4):

На моей системе срабатывает:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call('reboot')
```

В отличии от `Popen()`, `check_call()` выбросит исключение, если [`reboot`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/reboot.8.html) закончится неуспешно: к примеру, если другие пользователи активны — 
чтобы обойти это, можно попробовать:

```
subprocess.check_call(['systemctl', 'reboot', '-i'])
```

Последнее может быть опасным так как может прервать деликатные операции, такие как прошивка CD/DVD (порча диска).

---

Если у пользователя хватает прав, можно [используя  D-Bus API к systemd обратиться](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/dbus/):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pydbus  # apt install python3-gi && pip install pydbus

pydbus.SystemBus().get('.systemd1')['.Manager'].Reboot()
```

Вот реализация [systemctl в Питоне](https://github.com/LEW21/pydbus/blob/6be62734e6669b51274a9ef3beca85186c3aa29d/examples/systemctl.py).

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно сделать проще.

```
vi  /etc/sudoers
```

Закоментировать

```
# Defaults    requiretty
```

Добавляем в файл:

```
user   ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/test.sh
```

Даем права на ваш файл:

```
~ chown root:root /usr/your_directory/script.sh
~ chmod 755 /usr/your_directory/script.sh
```

И фсе.

Comment: вы используете vi вместо visudo, даете полные права для Всех пользователей скрипту test.sh, делаете рута владельцем скрипта script.sh, а в вопросе спрашивают про Python, мне кажется это не сработает.

Comment: да дырявим систему ради фигни)