# Как перезагрузить windows с помощью python?

Tags: python, windows-10

Нужно написать скрипт на python, который будет мониторить 1 процесс и при возникновении любой ошибки либо зависания процесса выполнять перезагрузку системы.

Comment: А что у вас уже получилось? Вопросы без попытки решения набирают часто - к карме и неохотно отвечаются.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Программная перезагрузка Linux c помощью Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/742255/23044)

Comment: зачем перезагружать систему?

Comment: Есть ПО майнер (Claymore's Dual) которая иногда зависает и помогает только перезагрузка системы. Сейчас это делается в ручную но хотелось бы как то автоматизировать.

Answer (score 4):

Модуль `subprocess` в python позволяет выполнять команды, в качестве подпрограммы, "как в консоли".

```
import subprocess
try:
    subprocess.check_all(['shutdown', '-r' '-t' ,'0'])
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

---

Также можно использовать модуль `os`

```
import os
os.system(['shutdown', '-r' '-t' ,'0'])
```

Этот вариант менее желателен, т.к. не отлавливает никаких ошибок и всё делает в данном окружении, в то время как `subprocess` создаёт дочернее окружение для выполнения программы.

---

Для мониторинга за процессом также используйте `subprocess`

```
import subprocess
try:
    process = subprocess.check_call('<команда>')
    process.wait(25)  # сколько секунд ждать
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
else:
    ...  # Ваш код
```

Comment: как минимум второй и третий примеры неверные.

Comment: @jfs это почему ещё?

Comment: если это не ясно, то задайте отдельные SO вопросы по каждому примеру (хотя ответ найти можно, просто прочитав что на входе, что на выходе в документации для каждой функции).

Comment: Ошибка, надо subprocess.check_**c**all

Comment: Вы сами-то их запускали? Второй и третий примеры всё ещё неверные.

Answer (score 4):

В дополнение к [варианту предложенному @MrMorgan](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/779770/211923) можно воспользоваться [pywin32](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/):

```
import win32api   # pip install pywin32

win32api.InitiateSystemShutdown()
```

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к другим вариантам, предложу свой с использованием модуля `os`:

```py
import os
os.system('reboot')
```